# Login error message object reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, error-handling

I have two pages called `Login.aspx` and `Home.aspx`

UPDATED CODE:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if (loginmethod(txt_us.Text, txt_pwd.Text) != "NA")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
                String strRole = Assignroles(txt_us.Text);
                FormsAuthenticationTicket fat = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txt_us.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, strRole, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat)));
                loginmethod(txt_us.Text, txt_pwd.Text);
                Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
            }
            else if (Session["ID"] != null)
            {

                    u = Session["ID"].ToString();  
            }

            else
            {
                Label1.Text = ("Incorrect UserName/Password");

                Label1.Visible = true;
                Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
            }
            txt_us.Text = "";
            txt_pwd.Text = "";
    }

    private string loginmethod(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            login_class lg_class = new login_class();
            Entities login = new Entities();
            string logn = Convert.ToString(lg_class.loginfunction(UserName, Password).Rows[0]["id"]);
            Session["ID"] = logn.ToString();
            return (logn);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {            
            return (ex.Message.ToString());            
        }
    }

    private string Assignroles(string username)
    {
        if ((txt_us.Text != string.Empty) && (txt_pwd.Text != string.Empty))
            return "";
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }

    public DataTable loginfunction(string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            Entities lg = new Entities();
            List<SP_GetLogin_Result> gr = lg.SP_GetLogin(username, password).ToList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            foreach (var l in gr)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(l.id);
            }
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
```

And on `home.aspx` page load:

```
    string id;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {   
            id = Session["ID"].ToString();
           this.FFID = "All";
            vehcileinfo(id);                     
        }    
    }
```

`SP_GetLogin` return ID i.e. when i enter username `abc` and pssword `1224` then this return ID `CU-2343`

when i enter with correct username and password then this redirect to `home.aspx`

But when i enter wrong username or password then this show an error on this line

```
u = Session["ID"].ToString();
```

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

And i want to show error message on `login.aspx` 
"incorrect username and password"

How i do this?

Comment: *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* It's shows that your `Session["ID"]` is `NULL`

Comment: Handle it: `if(Session["ID"] != null){ u = Session["ID"].ToString(); }`

Comment: ON home.aspx page ?? @Div and yes i enter wrong username and password that is why this error display where as i want to show message on login .aspx that incorrect username/password ..

Comment: @Div where i set this ?

Comment: @div  i do this on home.aspx ..  if(!IsPostBack)
            {
             
              
                id = u;
                this.FFID = "All";

                if (Session["ID"] != null) 
                { 
                    u = Session["ID"].ToString();
                }
                vehcileinfo(id);
            
            
            } when i enter wrong username and password then this redirect to home.aspx where as i want to show error message

Comment: When user enter credentials, then your `loginmethod` will be called, there you are checking and store `Entities` to session, check here if user enter wrong credential then you get null here `Session["ID"] = logn.ToString();`

Comment: on button click ? @Div

Comment: Yes,on button click

Comment: @Div check updated button code i try this and this show same error on home.aspx page load on this line u = Session["ID"].ToString();

Comment: please post your answer @Div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion in a comments, get an exception of `NullReferenceException`

Which means, you are trying to use something that is null. This means you either set it to null, or you never set it to anything at all.

So, just check on `Page_Load`of Home.aspx

```
if(Session["ID"] != null)
{ 
   id = Session["ID"].ToString();
} 

else
{
  // Do logic here
}
```

Comment: this is on login.aspx page load or on home.aspx load?

Comment: On `home.aspx` page load

Comment: i do this on home.aspx page load but this show when i enter wrong credentials then this redirect to home.aspx page  where as i want to show message and when i do this on button click login.aspx then this show same error which i posted on question

Comment: *show same when i enter wrong credentials* what do you mean it's still give an error?

Comment: now i do like this  if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                
              
                id = u;
                this.FFID = "All";
                u = Session["ID"].ToString();
              
                if (Session["ID"] != null)
                {
                    id = Session["ID"].ToString();
                }
                vehcileinfo(id);
            
            
            } this show error on this line  u = Session["ID"].ToString();

Comment: means same condition happening

Comment: Why you have written this `u = Session["ID"].ToString(); `